# iOS autolayout: how to extract all views from ASCII format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Say I have an **ASCII format** for `AutoLayout`:

```
V:|-20-[mybutton(>=70@500)]-[mylabel(==mybutton)]-30-[myimageview]-|
```

I need to extract all the views, that is, `UIButton`, `UILabel` and `UIImageView`, I thought about using `NSScanner`, and the logic is like:

1. scan up to `[`
2. scan up to character set including `[` and `(`
3. repeat from start to the end of the `String`

Is there any better approach?

What I need is the strings of views in the constraints, so from above example I need an array:

```
@[@"mybutton", @"mylabel", @"myimageview"]
```

Sorry for the misleading!

Comment: surely you already have the views since you are using them to populate the autolayout string already...

Comment: @Fonix Yes I do have all the views but I need to get all the strings for views, also, I may only have the constraint ASCII string without having actual view (ie. UIView).

Comment: yeah doing to backward from the constraint will be a lot of effort, i suggest trying to do it the way i mentioned in my answer ive just written

Answer (score 0):

use `NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1, view2, view3);`

which creates a dictionary where the keys are the variable names of the views, then you can extract the names via `[views allKeys]`